# jQuery selector jumps to next item when using splice() on Angular array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to select the dom object of an item just before deletion. I hook up the function below to a Delete button's ng-click inside the ng-repeated item, passing the $event object as an argument.

```
$c = $($event.target)
$c.css('background','red');
$scope.post[$postIndex].comments.splice($index,1);
```

The select is properly made, but after deletion/splice line (after the original DOM object is destroyed), **$c becomes the selector of the next item's delete button** - the styling is transferred. How is this possible?

Suspecting that Angular is faster than how jQuery selects the item, I've tried to wrap the deletion line in a $timeout, to no avail.

(I've tried to recreate this problem in a simpler jsfiddle unsuccesfully, after a possible answer, I'll update this post with possible interference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my research currently stands, this is just the way ng-repeat (and Angular, really) works: it reuses previous DOM elements (along with all their attributes). Editing DOM outside of Angular is [not supported](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3ea2416f8083a21bf2f47f3381a66bf97e7f59e2). Sometimes you can bypass this condition, but sometimes not...

**Update:** in this particular case the problem was that I used track by $index in my repeat, removing that will cure the DOM mismatch. However, this is still a messy solution, only advised if you don't want to edit that element anymore, and also includes performance penalties.

Answer (score 0):

That should solve it:

```
var targetID = '#' + $event.target.id;
$c = $(targetID);
$scope.post[$postIndex].comments.splice($index,1);
```

Comment: No, sadly the ID will get passed on too (as ng-repeat reuses repeated blocks)

Comment: I know it will, but the variable "targetID" should'nt change

Comment: The variable/selector doesn't change, but the DOM item in the view does (it wont refer to the original li item anymore, it will get reused for the next in the list)